# Does wing paint colour improve airplane fuel efficiency?

Tags: wing, fuel, efficiency, paint

If birds that fly very long distances like seabirds have darker colours on top of the wings and lighter colours underneath the wing, is it possible that painting airplane wings similarly may improve fuel efficiency?

Comment: It would probably do more to hide them from predators.

Comment: I hope so! I am getting my plane painted next month. Getting my ratty 30+ year old removed and some nice smooth stuff put on. Lighter cooler, less solar heating, should keep the fuel cooler, no?

Comment: @CrossRoads unless you have some overheating issue, heated fuel is beneficial for engine power.

Comment: Perhaps, but cool fuel is more dense yes? So more horsepower can be generated from the same gallon of fuel.

Comment: You'd have to calculate fuel $\alpha$ versus the increase in enthalpy. I was taught that heated fuel was beneficial, at least when dealing with JP4

Comment: I just came across this in another forum (cardinalflyers.com), backing up the need for keeping wing tanks cool:   Using a volumetric temperature expansion coefficient of .00053 (Gasoline Fahrenheit) and starting with 50 gallons at 60 degrees, once it gets to 110 degrees (with some sun baking) the volume changes by 1.35 gallons.

Comment: Please read this article in Journal of Thermal Biology - this colouration differential causes air pressure differential between the top and bottom of the wing, not unlike the force that drives the crookes radiometer. The name of the article is ‘Thermal impact of migrating birds’ wing color on their flight performance: Possibility of new generation of biologically inspired drones’

Answer (score 6):

I would doubt it.  The main issue with colour choice with airplanes is heat absorbed into the structure in sunlight, which tends to discourage dark colours.  Stand around a black painted light airplane on a hot sunny day and listen to the crinkle sounds as the skin expands and contracts as clouds put the wings in and out of shade.  If there was any effect, the distortion of the structure from heating (skins wrinkling) would *reduce* efficiency, if anything.

Aside from that, not a big problem for the structure with aluminum, but it is a problem for composites, especially room temperature cured homebuilt composite airplanes, where the sun can heat the skin to the epoxy's transition (softening) temperature.  This is why composite aircraft are almost always white, and if you see dark colours it will be on a structure that was post cured (heated while curing) to raise the transition temperature and make the finished structure more tolerant of high temperatures.

Comment: What do you think of the idea of using recycled aluminum, that would have dark colours/impurities already in the material, on the top of the wing, and pure reflective/white aluminum on the bottom? This would increase the pressure differential between the top and bottom of the wing, increasing lift and improving fuel efficiency, right?

Comment: Well you might as well paint the top flat black and the bottom white.  In the article you linked, they are theorizing that a hot upper surface reduces the density of the air right against the surface and this creates a small reduction in skin friction.  Could be.   My guess is any beneficial effect is too small to be significant on a wing moving at high speed, but it would be an interesting topic for someone's PhD thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Birds colors are made to protect them from predators. Just like military fighter jets. They have light colors on the bottom, so they will be less visible agains the sky when looking at them from below. Darker colors on top like camouflage, on the other hand, will hide them against the ground when looking at them from the sky.

I really doubt it will help you to save fuel. If you want to save fuel, you better not paint the aircraft at all to save weight. They did it during WWII. That's why those mustangs where all made in polished aluminum. The only part that was painted was the top of the nose, to protect the pilot from the glare.

Comment: Check out : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306456517300712